# BufferedReader reads older input

Tags: java, newline, inputstream, bufferedreader

Java beginner here. For testing, I made my own input class which uses BufferedReader. The code looks like this:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class inputter {

    private static BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    /**
     * @param
     * A reader for chars
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static char getChar() throws IOException{
        int buf= read.read();
        char chr = (char) buf;
        while(!Character.isLetter(chr)){
            buf= read.read();
            chr = (char) buf;
        }
        return chr;
    }

    /**
     * @param currencies, names
     * A reader for Ints
     * @throws IOException 
     * 
     */public static int getInt()throws IOException{
        String buf = read.readLine();
        while(!buf.matches("[-]?(([1-9][0-9]*)|0)")){
            buf = read.readLine();
            System.out.print("No valid input. Please try again.");
        }
        return Integer.parseInt(buf);
    }

     /**
         * @param currencies, names
         * A reader for Floats
         * @throws IOException 
         * 
         */
    public static float getFloat()throws IOException{
        String buf = read.readLine();
        while(!buf.matches("[-]?(([1-9][0-9]*)|0)(\\.[0-9]+)?")){
            System.out.print("No valid input. Please try again.\n");
            buf = read.readLine();
        }
        return java.lang.Float.parseFloat(buf);
    }

}
```

The problem with it is, whenever I read a char for example and after that try to read an integer, it jumps to the else condition and outputs `No valid input. Please try again`. I assume that is because there is old input(e.g. the newline char) flying around. How can I clean that up?

Comment: have you tried to debug your code? i think the problem is, that you can not convert a string (-> char[]) int a char. maybe the read buffer contains non-printable caracters?

Comment: I do not think that is the problem as it works fine multiple times and the error message is printed when Im only working with float and int as well.

Comment: How are you entering your input? Are you typging something like "a" [enter key] "1" [enter key]?

Comment: Wait! there is a big, big difference between a typecast and the Parsing-method of the Class Float or Integer!

Comment: I know. Maybe I do not understand what you are suggesting?! @Farlan, yes, that is how I do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while, I found it out myself eventually and rewrote the code. It now looks as follows and works perfectly(at least for me):

```
public static char getChar() throws IOException{ 
    String buf= read.readLine(); 
    char chr = (char) buf.charAt(0); 
    while(buf.length() <= 1 && !Character.isLetter(chr)){ 
        System.out.println("This is not valid input. Please try again."); 
        buf= read.readLine(); 
        chr = (char) buf.charAt(0); 
    } 
    read.readLine(); 
    return chr; 
}
```

I actually rewrote it again to be easier, but the outcome is slightly different:

```
public static char getChar() throws IOException{
        int buf= read.read();
        char chr = (char) buf;
        while(!Character.isLetter(chr)){
            buf= read.read();
            chr = (char) buf;
        }
        return chr;
    }
```

I use both of them regularly right now, but I'm still only a beginner, so I might rewrite both of them again.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is your input sequence:

Try entering the following sequence: "a1[enter]".  Your code should work for this kind of input.  However, if you enter "a[enter]1[enter]" your code should fail.
The reason is that the [enter] key is only processed when you do the next readline(), and it  will not match the number format, therefore going into your else condition.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this was not the problem. I found the bugged sequence. The problem was that the newline remained in the buffer. A simple read.readLine() behind the while sequence did the job.

Comment: public static char getChar() throws IOException{
  String buf= read.readLine();
  char chr = (char) buf.charAt(0);
  while(buf.length() <= 1 && !Character.isLetter(chr)){
   System.out.print("This is not valid input. Please try again.\n");
   buf= read.readLine();
   chr = (char) buf.charAt(0);
  }
  read.readLine();
  return chr;
 } is the valid code.